# There were merge conflicts for the shelveset "shelveset name", "user"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

when i tried to build a shelveeet, i got a error - There were merge conflicts for the shelveset "shelveset name", "user". why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

When you build a `shelveset`, TFS effectively unshelves the shelf into a working directory.  This is exactly the same as when a user unshelves a shelf into their own working directory.

The error is telling you that there was a conflict when this unshelving took place.  You can get more visibility into this by unshelving the shelf into a clean (latest) workspace on your own machine.  You should see the same conflict and `Visual Studio` will give you tools to resolve the conflict.

I would resolve the conflict and then reshelve.

**The Cause**

The most common cause is that a conflicting checkin has occurred on one of the shelved files.  Therefore when you try to unshelf, the automatic merge fails.

Answer (score 1):

There are times where a different user can unshelve into a clean workspace, create a new shelve set and a shelveset build will still fail with the same error.
This is especially true when adding new files.  The only solution I've found so far is to have the user check in the new files, remove them from the shelve set and try the shelve build again.